# Assembly 'call' vs 'jmp'

Tags: assembly, x86, subroutine

I got told to try and use 'jmp rather than 'call', but 'jmp' is not liking me .. when I jump it doesn't return (so it never exits and not happy days ), but calling returns and exits as normal.

I am happy using 'call' but is there actually a reason I should try and overcome 'jmp' ?

This simple code just shows if when I `jmp` it never returns and exits.

```
_start:

    jmp _Print
    jmp _Exit

ret


_Exit:

    ; normal exit 

ret


_Print

    ; print something

ret
```

also .. I'm running this all in a Linux terminal if that changes anything.

Comment: This is ambiguous, and very unclear. JMP doesn't set up the stack (by pushing the return value) so when you do a `ret`, a bogus return address gets popped off the stack and your code jumps to it. You can fake a `call` with a `jmp` but prior to doing jmp you must push the return address on the stack yourself. What assembler and what OS are you targeting? 16 or 32 bit?

Comment: I think your question might have an answer similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28133370/3857942 .

Comment: There is no reason I can think of (in this case) to use `JMP` instead, except to be done in school to teach you how a `CALL` and `RET` function together by simulating the `CALL` with `JMP`. It will also teach you something about the stack

Comment: Some of the answers on this thread might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205054/what-if-there-is-no-return-statement-in-a-called-block-of-code-in-assembly-progr?noredirect=1#comment69616101_41205054

Comment: The others answered it basically. cdecl and stdcall are part of the issue. `CALL` and `RET` are designed to build and tear down the stack depending on your calling convention. So by using `JMP` you don't build the stack appropriately. a `JMP` is more for loops or continuation of code elsewhere. In other words. a `CALL` is a `JMP` with the added feature of pushing the next instruction address onto the stack.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, first of all, `jmp` simply 'jumps' to the label that you give to it (which is a memory address as program instructions are stored in memory) while `call` stores the location where it will return (below the `call` instruction) in the stack, `jmp` to the label, and then at the `ret` instruction, `jmp` back to what location was stored (as said above, below the call instruction). A bit of a difference there as you can see. IMHO, i believe it is fine to simply `call` functions, as that is what the c++ compiler does with functions, but if you must `jmp`, then alright then, just make sure to `push` the return location or create another label to return to once done executing some code.

Here is an example of jumping to other label when done:

```
_start:



 jmp _Print;



_start_label:



 jmp _Exit;

_Exit:
 ; exit stuff goes here

 ret;     

_Print:

;print stuff goes here

jmp _start_label;
```

or you could just use call :)

Comment: That definitely clears things up thankyou! I have only just started learning assembly this week so it is good to get advice like this.